# Node Express Routing

Tags: node.js, express

I am struggling to understand the routing for express / jade, all of the examples I have seen are for only 1 page index.html, however what if you site has more than 1 page ?

in my /routes folder I have the following in the index.js file:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('index.jade', { title: 'Home'});
};

exports.sched = function(req, res){
  res.render('sched.jade', { title: 'Schedules' });
};
```

However, the sched.jade page is not rendered when I attempt to open the url: /sched

What am I doing wrong ??

Comment: If you're using a [generated application](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#executable), the `/routes` directory is intended for defining the actions of your application while actually binding them to their respective routes is [done in the `app.js` file](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/3.3.1/bin/express#L235-L236). The project's [`route-separation` example](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/tree/3.3.1/examples/route-separation) follows a similar concept, with `index.js` binding actions defined in `post.js`, `site.js`, and `user.js`.

Comment: Also, though they use a different router than Express, the [`npm-www` project](https://github.com/isaacs/npm-www) (source for [`npmjs.org`](https://npmjs.org/)) can still be a thorough example of route separation with [`~/router.js`](https://github.com/isaacs/npm-www/blob/master/router.js) binding their [`~/routes/`](https://github.com/isaacs/npm-www/tree/master/routes).

Answer (score 1):

In the file you call node on (usually app.js or server.js), you need to import the routes and then call the functions. For example:

```
var routes = require('routes/');

app.get('/sched', routes.sched);
app.get('/', routes.index);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working from a template you might have a file called 'boot.js', mine is in a lib folder. This file has all of the routing information. My routing has a switch that looks like this:

```
for (var key in obj) {
switch (key) {
    case 'show':
      method = 'get';
      path = '/' + name + '/:' + name + '_id';
      break;
    case 'index':
      method = 'get';
      path = '/';
      break;
    case 'services':
      method = 'get';
      path = '/services';
      break;
    default:
      throw new Error('unrecognized route: ' + name + '.' + key);
  }
```